# Independence of Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability

> A sequence of Bernoulli trials satisfies the following assumptions:
>
> 1. Each trial has two possible outcomes, in the language of reliability called success and failure.
> 2. The trials are independent. Intuitively, the outcome of one trial has no influence over the outcome of another trial.
> 3. On each trial, the probability of success is $p$ and the probability of failure is $1−p$ where $p \in [0,1]$ is the success
>      parameter of the process.

http://www.randomservices.org/random/bernoulli/Introduction.html

How is independence defined in this case? Is it pairwise independence or mutual independence? The probability of **particular** outcome ($k$ successes after $n$ trials) is given by $$p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

It implies we have to assume mutual independence (which is a stronger assumption than pairwise independence).

Let $S_i$, $i\in \mathbb{N}$, $1\le i \le n$ denote the event that we got success in $i$th trial, and $F_i$ - failure.

Therefore we require that (it's just one of many other conditions required by mutual independence) 
$$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)=P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3)$$

Obviously to talk about events, we need an appropriate sample space. A single outcome is a sequence of length $n$ of $S$ and $F$s. The event $S_i$ corresponds to all outcomes that have $S$ in the $i$th place.

Is there anything that should be added here? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: When left unspecified, independence usually refers to mutual independence. A sample space convenient for an unspecified number of trials is $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ the set of (infinite) sequences with values in $\{0,1\}$, where the $n$th entry of the sequence being $0$ or $1$ means the $n$th try is a failure or a success, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. We require mutual independence here. If we only have pairwise independence, we can let $A3 = A1 \mathbin{\oplus} A2$, where $\mathbin{\oplus}$ denotes xor. Then you can verify pairwise independence because 
\begin{align*} P(A_1 = a, A_3 = b) &= P(A_1 = a, A_2 = a \mathbin{\oplus} b) \\
&= P(A_1 = a)P(A_2 = a \mathbin{\oplus} b) = P(A_1 = a) P(A_3 = b) \end{align*}
But this is not a Bernoulli process